# Links in canvas (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I already know how to implement an user interface, I've done that. But I have lower FPS in certain moments. By doing a performance test with Firefox I noticed that those moments are when the browser re-calulates CSS.

It has to recalculate CSS because I modify the property "style" by inserting css rule "cursor: pointer". I'm doing that because in my canvas there are some links that needs a different cursor. But I want to optimize that feature to avoid freeze. Any ideas on how to do that?

My code does this: addEventHandler to canvas (mousemove), everytime the event fires it checks for cursor coordinates, and if my cursor coordinates are ON a link it changes cursor to "pointer", it also sets a variable called hoverIndex to the position of the link in the array.

```
var sky = new Image();
var logotype = new Image();
var back_btn = new Image();
var next_btn = new Image();
var upgrades_btn = new Image();

var coin_five = new Image();
var coin_ten = new Image();
var coin_fifty = new Image();
var cash_hundred = new Image();

var currentArea = "main_menu";
var cvn, ctx;

var linkAreas = [];
var hoverIndex = -1;

var gameVersion = "1.2.2a";

var coinFiveReset = 1500;
var coinTenReset = 5000;
var coinFiftyReset = 10000;
var coinHundredReset = 10000;

var coinFiveRemaining = 1500;
var coinTenRemaining = -1;
var coinFiftyRemaining = -1;
var coinHundredRemaining = -1;

var playingInterval;

//{type: "five", x: 0, y: 0}
var coinsPlaying = [];

function initialization(){
    cvn = document.getElementById("kg_coinfactory");
    ctx = cvn.getContext("2d");

    cvn.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev){
        var pos = getMousePosition(ev);
        for(var x = 0; x<linkAreas.length; x++)
            if(currentArea == linkAreas[x].area && pos.x >= linkAreas[x].x && pos.y >= linkAreas[x].y && pos.x <= linkAreas[x].x + linkAreas[x].width && pos.y <= linkAreas[x].y + linkAreas[x].height)
            {
                hoverIndex = x;
                cvn.style = "cursor: pointer";
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cvn.style = "";
                hoverIndex = -1;
            }
    });

    cvn.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
        if(hoverIndex != -1)
            linkAreas[hoverIndex].onClickFunc();
    });
}

function getMousePosition(ev){
    var rect = cvn.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x: ev.clientX - rect.left, y: ev.clientY - rect.top};
}

function registerLink(x, y, text, area, ctx, onClickFunc)
{
    var s = ctx.measureText(text);
    linkAreas.push({x: x, y: y - 24, width: s.width, height: 24, area: area, onClickFunc: onClickFunc});
}
```

Comment: You will need to post your code.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that.

Comment: Why do you erase the whole `canvas.style` if you just need to update its `cursor` property? change it to `cvn.style.cursor = 'pointer';` `else cvn.style.cursor = '';`

Comment: I'll do it. Anyway this doesn't resolve the freeze problem: By using that property css styles are re-calculated by browser as like as I'm using "cvn.style".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the FPS really drop that much to worry about?

Anyway, you could save the existing status of your cursor and only change it if the cursor moves in or out of the hover areas.

Or, if you don't need the canvas to respond to mouse events under the hover areas you could `position:absolute` a DOM element over the canvas and let that element respond to hover & click events.

Or, you could turn the pointer off when over the canvas and drawImage your own pointer(s).

Or, in the extreme, you could even overlay a second canvas over your existing canvas and drawImage just the pointer on that second canvas. Set `pointer-events:none` on that second canvas so your mouse events drop through to the existing underlying canvas.

BTW, your mouse position calculation can be more efficient.

Your `getMousePosition` calls `getBoundingClientRect` for every mousemove event. Instead, save the `rect.left` and `rect.top` and use those saved `offsetX` & `offsetY` values instead of using the more expensive getBoundingClientRect(). If the window resizes or scrolls you must recalculate the bounding box. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();

function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}

window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }
```

And calling an external function (you `getMousePosition`) does cause a small bit of extra processing so you might calculate the mouse position directly inside your mouse event handler.

Also, since you're handling the mousemove event yourself, you can save processing by telling the browser that it does not need to bubble this event to other elements:

```
// tell the browser we're handling this event
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

So a more efficient mouse event handler might look like this:

```
cvn.addEventListener("mousemove", function(ev){    

    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();

    // calc the mouse position directly in the handler
    // and use cached offset values
    mouseX=parseInt(ev.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(ev.clientY-offsetY);

    ... and now do stuff ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, and for your long answer. Anyway, I'm worried about the styles changing everytime I'm moving my mouse. So I added a piece of code that checks style.cursor's status, now it doesn't need to refresh styles everytime I move my mouse. In addition I modified the code as you said and I gained 6-7 FPS. Thank you again for your answer.